# simplify an if/else inside another else

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code, i need to put an if/else inside an else to change the DOM of my view:

```
else {
      this.selectedUser = this.user.find(b => b._id === userId)
      this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
      if (this.selectedUser.isConnected) {
        (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src = 'assets/imgs/userConnected.png'
      } else {
        (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src
          = 'assets/imgs/userDiscoonnected.png'
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to simplify this ? or make it more clean ?

Comment: you probably want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post all of the code if you are wanting to clean it  - not just that bit as we cannot tell what else you are trying to do

Comment: you can write like this `<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src = 'assets/imgs/${this.selectedUser.isConnected?'userConnected':'userDiscoonnected'}.png'` in easy way

Answer (score 0):

only readable way I can think of is

```
 else {
          this.selectedUser = this.user.find(b => b._id === userId)
          this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
          (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src =
          this.selectedUser.isConnected 
          ? 'assets/imgs/userConnected.png' 
          : 'assets/imgs/userDiscoonnected.png';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
  this.selectedUser = this.user.find(b => b._id === userId)
  this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)

  var imgPath = this.selectedUser.isConnected ? 'assets/imgs/userConnected.png' : 'assets/imgs/userDiscoonnected.png';

  (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src = imgPath;
}
```

A ternary operator looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `? :` to make a simpler if statement when you are comparing with a `bool`.

The statement on the left side of the `?` is the condition to be fulfilled. To the left of the `:` you place the value of the variable if the condition is true. On the right side of the `:` you place what the value should be if the condition turns out to be false.

```
var src = this.selectedUser.isConnected ? 'assets/imgs/userConnected.png' : 'assets/imgs/userDiscoonnected.png';
<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('user-state')).src = src;
```